# Menu items Wildcards and Parameter Replacement

Tags: 7, routes

It is my module code:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['mymodule/%f'] = array(
        'title' => 'My account',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_hello',
        'page arguments' => array(1), // The matched wildcard.
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
} 
function f_load($arg){
    return "the argument is : ".$arg;
}

function mymodule_hello($arg){
    return t($arg) ;
}
```

From what I know, when visiting a page like `/mymodule/12345`, function `f_load()` is automatically loaded and the result of `f_load(12345)` is sent to the call back function `mymodule_hello()`.

But the problem is visiting this page returns PAGE NOT FOUND error. what is the problem?

Comment: have you cleared drupal cache after adding a menu item?

Comment: @VishalPatil Yes

Comment: And the module's installed and enabled @Drupalist?

Comment: @Clive it is enabled, the above module without wildcard works well

Comment: @Clive Is there any difference whether the load function is in a file specified by `file =>` or it is in the `.module` file? I moved the load function from another file to the module file and it worked!

Comment: The load function needs to be in the .module file (or a file that you explicitly include through that file). The `file` option is for the page callback

Comment: @Clive thanks, what was the problem. I never thought the load function is not allowed to be in `file`